# Delete Tweet with Twitter Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

How do I delete a Tweet given it's ID?

I've tried `Twitter.status_destroy(1221312312)` to no avail (undefined method)

These also do not work:

`client.status(13123123123).delete`
`client.status(13123123123).destroy`

Comment: which gem are you using? have you checked the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documented here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Tweets#destroy_tweet-instance_method) is the `destroy_tweet` (aka: `destroy_status`) method.

Looks like it should be simply:

```
client.destroy_tweet 13123123123
```